# Number of strings of length 5??

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ternary strings of length $5$ contain at most two $0$s, at most two $1$s and at most two $2$s?

Is the working $3^5-(3)(5C3 + 5C4 + 5C5)$?Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: They'll all have two of one symbol, two of another and just one of the last.

Comment: So is the working correct?

Comment: Alas, I can't follow your argument, but I get a different number to you :-(

Comment: No, your working is not correct.  $3(5C3+5C4+5C5)$ only counts the number of bad strings which are formed with 3 or more of one of the numbers and all remaining spaces filled with the smallest unused number.

Comment: Then 3^5- that?

Answer (score 0):

> How many ternary strings of length five contain at most two 0s, at most two 1s and at most two 2s?

Your *approach* is to count ways not to have three or more of a digit.   That is okay.

> Or is there something I'm missing?

Indeed, you are neglegting the selection of the remaining digits.

$$3^5 - 3\left({}^5\mathrm C_3 \color{navy}{2^2}+{}^5\mathrm C_4 \color{navy}2+{}^5\mathrm C_5\right)$$

---

An alternate approach: count ways to select two pair and a single.

> $${}^3\mathrm C_1{}^5\mathrm C_2~{}^2\mathrm C_1{}^3\mathrm C_2\div 2!$$

Comment: Your alternate approach, although the theory is good, the calculations seem off to me.  Should it not instead be $\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ instead?  Choose which number is used a single time and its location, then choose the two locations from those remaining used by the smallest remaining number?

Comment: $\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}$ sounds like you are picking the "first" number used for the pair and its locations and then the "second" number used for a pair and its locations., falling into the same trap people often use for calculating two-pairs in poker calculations... that you can't distinguish between the two

Comment: Your first calculation yields $90$, while your alternate calculation yields $180$.  You need to multiply the second calculations by $1/2$ to avoid counting arrangements such as $01012$ twice (see the second comment by JMoravitz).